# После установки create react app в консоли сообщение [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS

Tags: webpack

После установки create react app в консоли следующее сообщение: [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS.... Вначале я не стал обращать внимание, но в процессе работы реакт перестал отображать какие-либо изменение, плюс начал выплевывать удаленные файлы в папке проекта. Я так понимаю проблема с webPack....подскажите из за чего она и как ее можно решить?

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, такая проблема стала появляться, начиная с "react-scripts": "3.3.0". 
Один из вариантов решения - понизить версию "react-scripts" до "3.2.0" в package.json

Либо настраивать вебпак:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53905253/cant-set-up-the-hmr-stuck-with-waiting-for-update-signal-from-wds-in-cons

Больше по теме:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8153